# How to package custom fonts into a .res file for FMX on Win32？

Tags: windows, delphi, fonts, firemonkey, embedded-resource

I found a GitHub project about FMX Win32 with custom fonts, but I don't know how to use them.

https://github.com/TheOriginalBytePlayer/FireMonkey-Fonts

The project needs to package fonts into a `.res` file. There is no demo to refer to. I tried: `1 rcdata“ my.ttf"` Or `1 font" my.ttf "`, both failed.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Resources and Images](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resources_and_Images) dialog?

Comment: I tried. It didn't work.

Comment: in what way? Please be more specific. What exactly did you try?

Comment: Thank you. I think it may be a problem with my font file. I'll just use it when I install it into the system.

Comment: This is a font that I disassembled from SWF. It's corrupted. I can find his full version on the Internet.